# Duda con promesas en Java Script

Tags: javascript

Les explico mi problema, Tengo una funcion llamada `renderMiniatura(urlFile);` que me renderiza un PDF con la ayuda de la libreria **pdfjsLib** Lo que quiero lograr es que una vez que se renderice el PDF generar una **URL** de ese canvas. y retornar esa **URL**. Aqui empieza el problema, cuando mando a llamar esta funcion tengo que esperar a que se termine de renderizar el PDF para que esté lista mi **URL**, mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para que mi funcion sea una **PROMESA** y asi obtener de manera correcta la URL ya lista.

Les comparto el codigo comentado que tengo hecho, Agredezco de antemano su ayuda.

```
//FUNCION QUE RECIBE COMO PARAMETRO LA URL DEL PDF

    function renderMiniatura(urlFile) {
      const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(urlFile);
      let objectURL;
    
// OBTENEMOS EL PDF

      loadingTask.promise.then((pdf) => {

//OBTENEMOS LA PAGINA DEL PDF

        pdf.getPage(1).then((page) => {
          let scale = 1;
          let viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: scale });
          let canvasElement = document.querySelector("#my-canvas");
    
          let context = canvasElement.getContext("2d");
    
          canvasElement.width = viewport.width;
          canvasElement.height = viewport.height;
    
          let renderTask = page.render({
            canvasContext: context,
            viewport: viewport,
          });
 /*
 AQUI ESTA LO QUE QUIERO LOGRAR !!!
 UNA VEZ QUE TERMINE DE RENDERIZAR
 CREO LA URL DEL PDF RENDERIZADO
 Y LO RETORNO

 */   
          renderTask.promise.then(function () {
            objectURL = canvasElement.toDataURL();
            return objectURL;
          });
        });
      });
    }
```

Comment: No funciona devolver la variable, porque tendrá un valor adecuado hasta que la promesa se resuelva. Dentro de la función haz lo que necesites en lugar de devolver `objectURL`.

Comment: @Triby Tienes razon, por eso cuando llamaba esa funcion nunca devolvía nada ya que aun no estaba lista esta variable, pero la respuesta de **Oscar Ludick** era justo lo que quería lograr, Agradezco mucho la ayuda brindada, Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente envuelve tu función en una promesa

```js
function renderMiniatura(urlFile) {
   //Promise Wrapper
   return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
      const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(urlFile);
      let objectURL;
  
      loadingTask.promise.then((pdf) => {

        pdf.getPage(1).then((page) => {
          let scale = 1;
          let viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: scale });
          let canvasElement = document.querySelector("#my-canvas");
    
          let context = canvasElement.getContext("2d");
    
          canvasElement.width = viewport.width;
          canvasElement.height = viewport.height;
    
          let renderTask = page.render({
            canvasContext: context,
            viewport: viewport,
          });

          renderTask.promise.then(function () {
            objectURL = canvasElement.toDataURL();
            //Resuelve la promesa
            resolve(objectURL);
          });
        });
      });
   });
  }
```

```js
renderMiniatura('').then(function(objectURL){console.log(objectURL)})
```

Comment: Justo lo que estaba buscando realizar. !Agradezco mucho tu ayuda!